# Usando tags unity 3D?

Tags: c#, jogos, unity-5

Nao consigo identificar meus prefabs com as tags que defini, ja adicionei as tags aos deviso prefabs como podem ver abaixo:
[image: Meus prefabs C, E H com as tags Carbono e Hidrogenio respectivamente]

e meu condigo:

```
public void Checks(){

    for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {
            if (Grid [x, y] != null) {

                if (Grid [x, y].tag == "CARBONO") {
                    Debug.Log ("EXISTE C: ");
                    if (Grid [x + 1, y].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                        cont++;
                    }
                    if (Grid [x - 1, y].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                        cont++;
                    }
                    if (Grid [x, y + 1].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                        cont++;
                    }
                    if (Grid [x, y - 1].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                        cont++;
                    }
                }
                Debug.Log ("contador: " + cont); //teste
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Eu coloquei um verificador pra saber se ele entra na condição de existir um C no meu grid, mas por mais que meu grid apareça o prefab C ele passa direto e não faz o restante das verificações.

A funçao que gera os meus prefabs aleatoriamente:

```
string GetRandomTetromino(){
    int randomTetromino = Random.Range (1, 5);
    string randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
    switch (randomTetromino) {
    case 1:
        randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/H";
        break;
    case 2:
        randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
        break;
    case 3:
        randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/H";
        break;
    case 4:
        randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
        break;

    }
    return randomTetrominoName;


}
```

e a função que joga a prefab gerada nas coordenadas ta dela:

```
public void SpawnNextTetromino () {
    if (!gameStarted) {

        gameStarted = true;
        nextTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(GetRandomTetromino(), typeof(GameObject)), new Vector2 (5.0f, 22.0f), Quaternion.identity);
        previewTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate (Resources.Load (GetRandomTetromino (), typeof(GameObject)), previewTetrominoPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        previewTetromino.GetComponent<Tetromino> ().enabled = false;

    } else {
        previewTetromino.transform.localPosition = new Vector2 (5.0f, 20.0f);
        nextTetromino = previewTetromino;
        nextTetromino.GetComponent<Tetromino> ().enabled = true;

        previewTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate (Resources.Load (GetRandomTetromino (), typeof(GameObject)), previewTetrominoPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        previewTetromino.GetComponent<Tetromino> ().enabled = false;
    }

}
```

aqui esta o repositorio do meu jogo: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/epm4dxbiwcjaxvp/AAC-SzKcXtZzGhd71CS45KXra?dl=0

Comment: O código a princípio está OK, logo, a gente precisa do código que insere os objetos dentro da tua Grid pra avaliar o real problema.

Comment: Esta funçao é a que gera os meus objetos randomicamente:
`string GetRandomTetromino(){
  int randomTetromino = Random.Range (1, 5);
  string randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
  switch (randomTetromino) {
  case 1:
   randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/H";
   break;
  case 2:
   randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
   break;
  case 3:
   randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/H";
   break;
  case 4:
   randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
   break;  
  }
  return randomTetrominoName; 
 }`

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta com este código, não só vai ficar legível quanto que comentários são pra meros detalhes e pra nós usuários poder fazer perguntas, qualquer informação útil tem de estar na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que vc deve tentar fazer assim. Pesquisar o game object pelo nome, porque se pesquisar pela tag, talvez traga todos os game object com nomes diferentes porém com a mesma tag.

```
GameObject randomTetrominoName = GameObject.Find("Prefabs/H");

switch (randomTetromino) 
{
    case 1:
        randomTetrominoName = GameObject.Find("Prefabs/H");
        break;
    ...
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Mas eh nessa funçao que ele cria o objeto do jogo, se eu colocar conforme vc citou, nao sera exibido nenhum objeto na tela.

Answer (score -1):

Para acessar o prorpiedade "tags", dependendo do lugar em que seu componente tenta acessar voce precisar especificar "gameObject" na frente do componente.